# When i Submit model data, i get <p> tag in response

Tags: javascript, jquery, model, response, paragraph

My model: **xyz.php**

```
 public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'phone',
        'status',
    ];
```

```
protected $casts = [
        'id'      => 'integer',
        'phone'   => 'string',
        'status'  => 'boolean',
    ];
```

**table**:

```
 $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
```

**JS file code**:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#addNewForm', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: userCreateUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    displaySuccessMessage(result.message);
                    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
                }
            },
    }):
```

**blade.php**
[blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8RoK.png)

[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQvsF.png)
When I submit data from the model, I get a response to the data according to the photo above, e.g., 
`phone = "<p>1234567890</p>"`. Please some solutions. Thank you advance.

Comment: How do you enter the information. Do you enter the information using <input> tags? Could you please post the html.

Comment: hello Thomas,
i added my blade file screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely when you use the `serialize` method. Instead i have written a function that can extract the input values from the form. You can then send this information to your server.

```
 function getInputValues(form){
     var values = {};
     form.find(':input').each(function() {
          values[this.name] = $(this).val();
     });

     return values
 }
```

You can use this function like so:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#addNewForm', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: userCreateUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: getInputValues($(this)),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    displaySuccessMessage(result.message);
                    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
                }
            },
    }):
```

However you should note that all the returned values are string, even if you used an input with `type="number"`. The alternative to this solution, is to manually extract each input value using a specific id.

`const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('#phone-number-input').value`.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank u for replay,
I tried your code but, got same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the `p` tags then before inserting into the db use `strip_tags()`.